# How to debug two processes in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

In my application an activity starts a service which runs as a separate process, I want to debug the Activity as well as the service but debugger does not stop at the breakpoints in service?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It should :-). There's no reason why the service breakpoints wouldn't get hit.

Are you able to successfully stop at breakpoint in the activity you are using to launch the service?

Comment: @tomtheguvnor In Activity, Yes.

Comment: Temporarily make it not be a separate process. Better yet, permanently make it not be a separate process, as that is generally unnecessary and is wasteful of RAM and CPU.

Comment: @CommonsWare I will rethink my design. Is there no way except "Temporarily make it not be a separate process"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporarily make it not be a separate process.

@CommonsWare

Answer (score 14):

Just to elaborate on the other answers here, you can temporarily put `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` in the code of your secondary process to make this easier.

Then, just attach your debugger to the process via DDMS or IntelliJ (or whatever you're using).

Comment: Official-ish sounding advice from a google employee to back this up: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/DftP5gYcwYI/j_mccTSCHNQJ

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable debugging on the separate process.

Open the DDMS perspective (as oposed to Debug or Java). In DDMS->Devices, select your service's process and then click the debug button (little-green-bug button). A debug icon will appear near your process, then you should be able to use breakpoints in your Service.

Note that you need to wait until the remote process starts before enabling debugging. So you may want to ensure the seperate process starts on boot, or set a breakpoint in your main process immediately after the line that starts the remote service.

Before enabling debugging:

[image]

After enabling debugging:

[image]

(of course temporarily making the service non-remote works too, but I've had an instance where that wasn't practical)

Comment: +1, Appreciate the answer. I am not using two processes anymore therefore I will let the community vet the answer before I accept it.